# Unable to run mysqli_result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$user_id = mysqli_result($query_result, 0, student_id’);
```

I want to bring the student_id from the database for the student that logged in

Comment: `mysqli_result` is a class, not a function

Comment: another cause might be `‘student_id’`, which should have been `'student_id'`  (look at the quotes...)

Comment: @luuk I’m typing with my phone. That’s why my ‘ is like that